# How to change the foreground_color of selected text of TextInput in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

I want to make a text editor using kivy TextInput .. It's hard but i am left with no choice.I want to add a method that changes the selected text's `foreground_color` . However I cant figure out how to do it. Is their a way to do this or does kivy provide a better widget to use for this purpose.

Comment: The [Label](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#markup-text) allows what you want, but does not have the interactive capabilities of `TextInput`.

Comment: Their is not even a single way??

Comment: You can change the `selection_color`, which does not change the text's `foreground_color`, but is the color of a `Rectangle` that is drawn over the selected text. But you can only have one `selection_color` at any time.

Comment: Can u plz tell me how can i access the start and end index of the selected text

Comment: See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.selection_from).